# How to add Correlation-Id as header with value format as UUID in java api calls?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to add `Correlation-Id` in logs in my Java Spring boot application. Which is having swagger yaml to generate controllers and models.

I know how to generate random UUID using below

```
private String generateUniqueCorrelationId() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
```

I know how to add this in logs as well.

But how can i add this as **Header** in all Api calls, so that when API is hit this `Correlation-Id` is added to header with `UUID` value. Which i can use in my logs.

Comment: have you tried to write an interceptor or use spring aop yet ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using a OncePerRequestFilter:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@Component
public class CorrelationIdFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
      FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            var id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            response.addHeader("correlation-id", id);
            MDC.put("correlation-id", id);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove("correlation-id");
        }  
    }
}
```

Important is the order that it is actually happening as the first filter.

Also you can add the correlation id to the mdc so its added to all the logs aswell.

Please let me know if this works, as adding a header is apparently depending on the version of spring you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

1- As mentioned by @Loading, you can do this by using a OncePerRequestFilter:

```
public class MDCFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final String X_REQUEST_ID = "X-Request-ID";
    private final String MDC_KEY = "UUID";

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final FilterChain chain)
            throws java.io.IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            final String uuid;
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(request.getHeader(X_REQUEST_ID))) {
                uuid = request.getHeader(X_REQUEST_ID);
            } else {
                uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString().toUpperCase().replace("-", "");
            }

            MDC.put(MDC_KEY, uuid);
            response.addHeader(X_REQUEST_ID, uuid);

            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } finally {
            MDC.remove(MDC_KEY);
        }
    }
}
```

It allows the client to have their own "X-Request-ID". if client doesn't provide it, it will be assigned.

2- In a @Configuration class, add this bean:

```
 @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<MDCFilter> servletRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<MDCFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        MDCFilter mdcFilter = new MDCFilter();
        registrationBean.setFilter(mdcFilter);
        registrationBean.setOrder(2);
        return registrationBean;
    }
```

- Additional things you can do:
- Utilize it for logging:

```
<pattern>%-5level| %t | [%X{UUID:-application}] | %logger{36} | %m %n</pattern>
```

- Utilize it for internal API calls:

```
.header("X-Request-ID", MDC.get("UUID"))
```

Comment: where to import this MdcFilter class ?

Comment: @Ravi I've updated my answer with a missing bean definition, that should take care of it. you dont need to import it anywhere.